# How I can know whats new in specific version of spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to know which changes spring has in his 1.5.9 version, and in 2.0 version,
how I can find a list or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing:

- the [Spring framework](https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/), in release 5.0.2 as of today, which is [an application framework and inversion of control container for the Java platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework)
- [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), a [convention-over-configuration solution for creating stand-alone, production-grade Spring-based Applications that you can "just run"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Spring_Boot), currently in release 1.5.9, with an impending 2.0.0rc1 release.

You can find the release notes [here](https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/28/spring-boot-1-5-9-available-now) for release 1.5.9, and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes) for release 2.0.0.